# Missing page ids in HTML source

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to apply css to a particular Wordpress page:

https://www.nickbettes.co.uk/small-businesses-leadership

I read that I should use page-id for this. I have the relevant page id but the css does not work.

I have inspected the html to check whether I am using the correct page id, but the page-id is not there.

Instead, I see this (I had to remove all the element separators):

```
"body class=" customize-support" style="" script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.nhyund4.com/js/102075.js"/script> noscriptimg alt="" src="http://www.nhyund4.com/102075.png" style="display:none;" //noscript><div class="header"..."
```

I have investigated nhyund4, but I've found almost nothing about it. Where is the page-id?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you're missing the [`body_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) function. In your theme, edit the `header.php` file and find the opening `<body>` tag.

Add the `body_class()` function to the body tag like so...

```php
...

</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

...
```

Always have a backup before making changes, just incase!

Comment: @nick_b Please accept this answer if it answered you question. Many thanks.

Comment: Levi I would love to - in fact I tried to mark it closed before - but it is not obvious how to do this!